# Google Map: Как получить названия городов, отмеченных маркерами?

Tags: php, яндекс-карты, google-maps

Можно ли получить названия городов, на которые пользователь поставил маркеры? Можно и Yandex карты использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);                
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                s = results[1].formatted_address;                       
                alert(s]);                              
                            }
                        } else 
                        {
                            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
marker.getPosition().lat()
marker.getPosition().lng()
```

алсо, доки не для людей: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ru-RU#LatLng

Comment: Про эти вещи я в курсе, меня интересует по координатам получить название городов: Россия, Беларуссия, Украина

Comment: Может есть нормальные mysql готовые таблицы с городами, что бы можно по координатам вытащить от туда

Comment: Боюсь, что если юзер будет "тыкать" на координаты, то в таблице должен быть большой диапазон координат для каждого города.

Comment: Есть написаный код для округления координат, к ближайшим города.